# How to paste data from one worksheet under changing data from another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I've been extensively researching this question but none of my findings have helped me fix my code.

I'm trying to copy all the data from `worksheet2` and paste directly under the data from `worksheet1` (which changes every month). This is what I have so far but every time I try to run it, it says

> Runtime Error 9 'Subscript out of range'.

```
Sub macro8()
    Sheets("worksheet2").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("worksheet1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets("worksheet2").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("worksheet1").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: @RamAnuragi same error :(

Comment: That error could mean that it cannot locate a worksheet with that name. Keep in mind both worksheets must be in the same workbook for these codes to work.

Comment: `1` Do you have more than 1 workbook opened? `2` If no, then are you sure your worksheet names do not have any leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: The other error you will get once you have sorted that is because of `Sheets("worksheet1").End(xlUp)`

Comment: so @RamAnuragi code somewhat worked, after I removed trailing spaces. thank you guys. however, this code replaced my previous data instead of pasting It under

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub macro8()
Sheets("worksheet2").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("worksheet1").UsedRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```

Edit:

Then do it the right way. You can change the column letter "A" with the letter of your continuous Column.

```
Sub macro8()
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("worksheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("worksheet2")
Set Rng2 = ws2.UsedRange 'Copy range
Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'Paste range

Rng2.Copy Destination:=Rng1 'Copy/Paste
End Sub
```